# More efficient way of appending dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append, concatenation

I was running some tests and found out that this piece of code here is inefficient. Looping in range of dates, if `self.query` is in `df` then appends the line, pretty straight forward. But I heard many opinions, that appending like this isn't efficient and even resource hungry.
My parquets have 4 columns with milions of lines - `query` `phone_count` `desktop_count` `total`, dropping 2 cols which means I have `index`, `query` and `total` and then the magic happens.

This code is working "fine", but now I'm looking for opinions from experienced users and possibly getting some hints.

Is there a way of doing the same in more efficient way? Tuples maybe?

Thank you, guys!

```
    for filename in os.listdir(directory):
        if filename.endswith(".parquet"):
            df = pd.read_parquet(directory).drop(["phone_count","desktop_count"], axis=1)
            df.set_index("query", inplace=True)

            if self.lowercase == "on":
                df.index = df.index.str.lower()
            else:
                pass
            if self.sensitive == "on":                            
                self.datafr = self.datafr.append(df.filter(regex=re.compile(self.query), axis=0))
            else:            
                self.datafr = self.datafr.append(df.filter(regex=re.compile(self.query, re.IGNORECASE), axis=0))            


self.datafr = self.datafr.groupby(['query']).sum().sort_values(by='total', ascending=False)
```

Comment: Can you explain what the regex is doing?

Comment: 1st Regex there: let's say if the query is "Facebook". Script is then looking only for "Facebook" and not "facebook". First is really case sensitive to the query and second is ignoring the case of the query. You can have "FaCEboOk" there as a query and it's gonna find "facebook" and "Facebook" too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are repeating a few things with each loop:

- The regex pattern does not need recompiling every time
- Repeated `DataFrame.append` is slower than `pd.concat([frame1, frame2, ...])`
- `list.append` is a lot faster than `DataFrame.append`

Try this:

```
option = re.IGNORECASE if self.lowercase == "on" else 0
pattern = re.compile(self.query, option)
subframes = []

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith(".parquet"):
        df = pd.read_parquet(directory).drop(["phone_count","desktop_count"], axis=1)
        df.set_index("query", inplace=True)

        # Not sure if this statement is necessary. The regex
        # is already IGNORECASE when lowercase == "on"
        if self.lowercase == "on":
            df.index = df.index.str.lower()

        # Multiple list.append
        subframes.append(df.filter(pattern, axis=0))

# But a single pd.concat
self.datafr = pd.concat([self.datafr] + subframes)
```

Comment: Thanks for an answer! I'm about to try it soon then I'll leave a feedback. :)

Comment: Getting TypeError: 're.Pattern' object is not iterable in the .append(df.filter(pattern, axis=0)) Looks like list doesn't like it

Comment: No, I'm just dumb. Forgot the df.filter(REGEX=pattern, axis=0) in the appending.